# Javascript/Canvas. Проседает FPS

Tags: javascript, массивы, canvas, оптимизация

Всем доброго времени суток!
Я пишу код на Javascript. Задача следующая: нужно отрисовать изображение на canvas, при этом предварительно применив к нему фильтры.
Проблема: Сильно проседает FPS.
Задумка была такая: пробегаемся по всем пикселям циклом ***for***. Значения каждого пикселя передаем в функцию-фильтр, которая преобразует входные данные и возвратит нужный цвет. После для текущего пикселя мы поменяем значение в общем массиве пикселей и отресуем все на canvas. Как-то так. FPS проседает как раз-таки при передаче значений пикселя.

Вот пример кода:

```
for (var y = 0; y < this.canvas.height; y++) {
    for (var x = 0; x < this.canvas.width; x++) {
        var index = getIndex(x, y); *//Проседает в этой части*
        var pix = {
            r: imgData.data[index],
            g: imgData.data[index + 1],
            b: imgData.data[index + 2]
        };
        var color = calcGrayScale(pix);
        this.setPixel(index, color);    
    }
}

function getIndex (x, y) {
    return y * canvas.width * 4 + x * 4;
}

function setPixel (index, color) {
    imgData.data[index] = color.r;
    imgData.data[index + 1] = color.g;
    imgData.data[index + 2] = color.b;
    imgData.data[index + 3] = 255;
}
function calcGrayScale(pix) {
    var color = (pix.r + pix.g + pix.b) / 3;
    return { r: color, g: color, b: color };
}
```

Пример другого кода:

```
var color = { r: 0, g: 0, b: 0 };
for (var i = 0; i < data.data.length; i += 4) {
    color.r = data.data[i];
    color.g = data.data[i + 1];
    color.b = data.data[i + 2];

    color.r = color.b = color.g = (color.r + color.g + color.b) / 3;

    data.data[i] = color.r;
    data.data[i + 1] = color.g;
    data.data[i + 2] = color.b;
}
this.ctx.putImageData(data, 0, 0);
```

Данный код тоже применяет Серый фильтр, но FPS уже не проседает.
Вопрос: как стоит поступить, если мне предпочтительнее первый вариант?

Вот пример работы: (Вначале отрисовывается нужное изображение, а после мы манипулируем пикселями)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: подход не правильный, опишите что нужно нарисовать залейте мокапы

Comment: @SergeEsmanovich, А как по-другому тогда, если не так? Можно какой-нибудь совет, пожалуйста?

Comment: какая высота/ширина у демо картинки?

Comment: Смотрите в сторону шейдеров.

Comment: @SergeEsmanovich, а почему подход не является правильным? И не объясните, пожалуйста: почему первым способом FPS проседает? P.S. я новичок в js.

Comment: @Grundy, 300 на 300 пикселей.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian, спасибо за ответ :) Но дело в том, что я не хочу их использовать. Хочется научится манипулировать пикселями без шейдеров.

Comment: @Рифат что нужно получить на выходе?, есть исходное цветное, я так понимаю нужно получить черно-белое?  Просто есть разные алгоритмы матричные, ими быстрее обрабатывать. Можно ещё тут глянуть http://codepen.io/JvanderHeide/pen/ojQPoV

Comment: И вот ещё просто для примера http://codepen.io/tmrDevelops/pen/azverW

Comment: @SergeEsmanovich, спасибо за ссылки :) Можете сказать почему первым способом (при получении пекселя сторонним методом) падает FPS?

Comment: @Рифат, например потому, что в первом способе в 4 раза больше операций чем во втором

Comment: @Grundy, а как можно переделать/доработать первый способ, чтобы он оставался производительным? Дело в том, что фильтры я хочу использовать как отдельные методы.

Comment: может быть проблема оптимизатора v8, например такое поведение бывает если в переменную выплёвыаеться NaN